# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException in HashMap

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

```
public class ReadToHashmap {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("example.tab"));
    String line = "";
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        String parts[] = line.split("\t");
        map.put(parts[0], parts[1]);
    }
    in.close();
    System.out.println(map.toString());
 }
}
```

while inserting the key with value in `HashMap`I am getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException` exception on:-

```
map.put(parts[0], parts[1]);
```

Comment: You don't seem to be checking the number of elements in the `parts` array before assuming it has at least two elements.

Comment: The question title is misleading as `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException` isn't  thrown by any method of `HashMap` but by the String array `parts[]` whose length in some case is less than 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String parts[] = line.split("\t");
```

Because you are expecting that each of the input `String` will be separated by tab space. But that is not happening for at least one input. Please check the input. That is why you are getting an exception here.

```
map.put(parts[0], parts[1]);
```

To debug this, you can print the content (`line`) and length (`parts.length`) to `System.out` just before putting them into the `HashMap`.

Comment: actually i have a file in which after running through a algorithm it gives me output in 2 columns but data in columns vary. for examle:-- first  line     12  1212 second line 1213123  213321. there are two spaces in between

Comment: Can you provide some sample of how the columns vary?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could replace

```
map.put(parts[0], parts[1]);
```

with

```
if(parts!=null && parts.length>=2)  
   map.put(parts[0], parts[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to split the `line` with `tab`, and for sure they are not being splited  thats why it is giving you `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException in HashMap`.

if you are using any IDE then debug it.

and Make sure `TAB` is equal to **4-spaces** not **2-spaces** as you mentioned, this is the reason why it is not splited.

**Update**

Apart from your problem , always use null checks and size checks before using the arrays of collections if you are getting it from some logic as you need min length of 2.

```
 while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        String parts[] = line.split("\t");
        map.put(parts[0], parts[1]);
    }
```

rather use

```
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        String parts[] = line.split("\t");
        if(parts!=null && parts.length>=2){
            map.put(parts[0], parts[1]);
        }
    }
```